# How to pass Devise's current_user as user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm practicing my Ruby on Rails by creating a simple application where users can sign up (using Devise) and post articles.

After installing Devise, I go ahead and generate a scaffold for the articles

```
 rails g scaffold article title:string article:text user_id:integer
```

Then I create the Devise user controller

```
rails generate devise User
```

My article controller:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My user controller:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Now my question is: how do you make it so that user_id in http://localhost:3000/articles/new/ is automatically current_user.id?

Also, in http://localhost:3000/articles/ the user should only be able to view the articles associated with their user_id, not anyone elses. What changes to the articles controller should I make to do this?

It's my first time posting here at Stack Overflow and your help would be appreciated.. Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT** found the solution to the first question, for future reference.

I put

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

in _form.html.erb, and

```
def create
    @article.user_id = current_user.id 
    ...
end
```

to my article controller. This is successfully passing the current_user.id as the article's user_id perfectly.

Comment: Please be more specific. You make little sense.

Comment: I thought I explained it as well as I could.. but ok, TL;dr --> the articles table has 3 fields (title, article, and user_id). I'm asking how user_id in the create form can = current_user.id from Devise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now my question is: how do you make it so that user_id in http://localhost:3000/articles/new/ is automatically current_user.id?

You should add to articles_controller's "def new" this line
@ask.user_id = current_user.id

so then `form_for @ask` asks for the `user_id` property of `@ask` and displays it. But I do not recommend doing this in a real-world app, where you probably would handle this step in "def create" of `articles_controller

> `Also, in http://localhost:3000/articles/ the user should only be able to view the articles associated with their user_id, not anyone elses. What changes to the articles controller should I make to do this?

inside `articles_controller`'s `def index`, change to `@articles = Article.where(user_id:current_user.id)`. Note that you should also add a `before_filter :require_user` to make sure that `current_user` is not nil.

Comment: ^^ Thanks. I think I figured it out. I put <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %> in _form.html.erb and @article.user_id = current_user.id under article_controller's 'def create' this is passing the current_user.id as the article's user_id perfectly. Your second solution makes sense; I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: @cdotfeli Setting the user_id in the form and not checking it afterwards means that you can impersonate any user of your site by doing a manual POST request.

Comment: @P.S.V.R. Your second solution worked!! Thanks a whole bunch. I'll go add that before_filter :require_user now.

Comment: @BenoitGarret so I SHOULDN'T pass the user_id as a hidden field in the form? What should I do instead? Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: @cdotfeli Sorry, I misread your solution. You're not actually using the `hidden_form` tag in your controller (you would have if you used `params[:article][:user_id]`). `@article.user_id = current_user.id` is perfect, but you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 4):

In your ArticleController#new action add the following line:
`@article = current_user.articles.build`

As for your index action:
`@articles = current_user.articles`